# How to seek for partial data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website that use data attributes putting the name of the data inside the value along the value itself.

```html
<div data-title="Subscribers: 4,471"></div>
```

I would like to know how to grab this `div` based on partial value that the div should contain "Subscribers", something like this (the * represent the pattern to seek for):

```py
test = soup.find_all("div", {"data-title": "Subscribers"*})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and check if attribute value:

**starts** with your pattern

```
soup.select('[data-title^="Subscribers"]')
```

**ends** with your pattern

```
soup.select('[data-title$="Subscribers"]')
```

**contains** your pattern

```
soup.select('[data-title*="Subscribers"]')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div data-title="Subscribers: 4,471"></div>
<div data-title="Views: 1,000"></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('[data-title^="Subscribers"]')
```